# How representative is the number of people who resize their browsers?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, grid, screen-resolution, media-queries

When you build a responsive site, you have media queries. As long as the screen is more or less the size of common media queries, for example Bootstrap's defaults, a design will probably look as expected. However, if you resize the browser window, chances are the design won't collapse properly. This is a very common issue with navigation menus.

Now, my question: **is the amount of users who resize their browsers really representative**? And if so, **what happens in terms of usability if I do not adjust the sizes for all possible sizes in which a user can change the size of the browser window?**?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your breakpoints but you may be over thinking it.

Responsive design works for a range of sizes. Say your break points are 480, 640, 720, 1020 and 1400.

Would it really matter if someone set his screen at 1030 or 1060? Your page would render with the 1400 pixel CSS.  Ideally you would be utilizing a fluid design and the design would work well just as well at 1060 as it does at 1400.

To put it differently: let's assume that the user had his screen at 1399 pixels. Your 1400px CSS would appear. Would your page render well at 1399 instead of 1400? I certainly hope so.    :)

How about 1390?

1380?

1280?

1180?

1080?

In each of these cases your design ought to work well. If it doesn't then you would need another break point.

The same should hold for:

1060

1030

1021

All the way to your break point of 1020.

The size your user sets his browser should not make a difference within the breakpoints.